# Default parameter given for parameter X of function Y

Tags: c++, parameters

I am trying to assign a default value to a parameter in this function declaration:

```
bool gatt_db_service_set_active(struct gatt_db_attribute *attrib, bool active, int fd=0);
```

However, I am getting error

> default argument given for parameter 3 of 'bool gatt_db_service_set_active(gatt_db_attribute*, bool, int)' [-fpermissive]

Then it says:

> previous specification in 'bool gatt_db_service_set_active(gatt_db_attribute*, bool, int)' here:
>    bool gatt_db_service_set_active(struct gatt_db_attribute *attrib, bool active, int fd;<

Which points to the same function declaration.

This is the definition:

```
bool gatt_db_service_set_active(struct gatt_db_attribute *attrib, bool active, int fd) 
{
    //stuff
}
```

As you can see I did not set the default parameter twice, as is the problem with most questions regarding this error. I am compiling this with `gcc version 5.2.1` on `Ubuntu 15.1`

Does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: Are you sure your file has cpp not c extension ?

Comment: I'm sure, it's all C++. Although this error happened when porting from C to C++. The strange thing is that other functions from different header files work fine with default parameters.

Comment: Couldn't duplicate: http://ideone.com/n3gK9i

Comment: @erip I see, that's even stranger!

Comment: Are you missing an include guard? Defining the same thing twice gives that error: https://ideone.com/9f2gtN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have somehow declared the function twice (so that the compiler sees two lines like this):

```
bool gatt_db_service_set_active(struct gatt_db_attribute *attrib, bool active, int fd=0);
```

Then you will see this error, because there are two declarations with a default, which is not allowed by the C++ standard (section 8.3.6, para 4):

```
... A default argument shall not be redefined by a later declaration.
```

This [example code](http://ideone.com/9f2gtN) demonstrates the error. Note that you *can* multiply-declare a function if you don't redefine the defaults, which might be useful for a forward declaration.

This could be because of a missing include guard, in which case the compiler will tell you both declarations are on the same line. You might have this situation in the following case:

```
// header.h
// No include guard!
bool gatt_db_service_set_active(struct gatt_db_attribute *attrib, bool active, int fd=0);
// ^^ compiler error on this line

// otherheader.h
#include "header.h"

// impl.cpp
#include "header.h"
#include "otherheader.h"

void main()
{}
```

The solution is an include guard like this:

```
// header.h
#ifndef HEADER__H_
#define HEADER__H_

bool gatt_db_service_set_active(struct gatt_db_attribute *attrib, bool active, int fd=0);

#endif // HEADER__H_
```

This will prevent the second (and subsequent) inclusions of `header.h` declaring the same thing twice.

Comment: Great answer! It's clear and the solutions and examples given will surely help me and hopefully future readers solving this problem!

Answer (score 4):

It turned out that there were no header guards in the header where I was declaring the function.

I found it strange the error was pointing to itself, so I tried to solve it by simply adding a header guard like `#ifndef FOO`and `#define FOO` at the top and `#endif` at the bottom. This worked.

Thanks to [Inductiveload](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1381158/inductiveload) for the pointer!